# Pub/Sub notification for GCS - event filter doesn't work

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-pubsub

What I wanted is whenever (and only when) a file is created on GCS, my pub/sub subscription can receive a notification.

So I did this:

```
gsutil notification create -t projects/[my-project-id]/topics/new-raw-file -f none -m eventType:OBJECT_FINALIZE gs://[the-target-bucket]
```

I think this config is set up successfully, because when I ran `gsutil notification list`  , it shows:

```
projects/_/buckets/[the-target-bucket]/notificationConfigs/7
Cloud Pub/Sub topic: projects/[my-project-id]/topics/new-raw-file
Custom attributes:
    eventType: OBJECT_FINALIZE
```

This is the only config.

However, other than file creation, I also receive file deletion notification:

```
Received 1 messages.
* 118758642722910: message - , attributes - {u'resource': u'projects/_/buckets/[the-target-bucket]/objects/2466870.3.txt#1493038968423735', u'objectId': u'2466870.3.txt', u'bucketId': u'[the-target-bucket]', u'notificationConfig': u'projects/_/buckets/[the-target-bucket]/notificationConfigs/7', u'payloadFormat': u'NONE', u'eventType': u'OBJECT_DELETE', u'objectGeneration': u'1493038968423735'}
```

didn't get what was going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I misused one command option. According to [this page](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/notification), "-m" actually just append a key:value attribute to the notification, it has nothing to do with the event filter that I wanted. The right option to use should be "-e" . So, the following config command actually works properly:`enter code here`

```
gsutil notification create -t [TOPIC_NAME] -f json  -e OBJECT_FINALIZE gs://[BUCKET_NAME]
```